# How to terminate DB request reported by org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport.reportSlowQuery in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I am using jdbcInterceptors as below:

```
< org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReportJmx(threshold=10000) in tomcat context.xml. >
```

Can I somehow configure to terminate that request if its active for 3-4 min and not responding ??

> 23-May-2016 09:00:54.679 WARNING [tomcat-http--20]
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport.reportSlowQuery
>   Slow Query Report SQL=SELECT***; time=11082 ms;
>           23-May-2016 11:08:19.661 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.notifyStuckThreadDetected
>   Thread "tomcat-http--19" (id=132) has been active for 605,101
>   milliseconds (since 5/23/16 10:58 AM) to serve the same request for
>   http://** and may be stuck (configured threshold for this
>   StuckThreadDetectionValve is 600 seconds). There is/are 1 thread(s) in
>   total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.
>            java.lang.Throwable
>             at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:591)
>             at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:582)